# Reading and counting (double precision) real numbers from file with non-advancing I/O: what edit descriptor to use?

Tags: fortran

I am trying to read a list of real numbers from an external file into an array. I do not know how many <del>records</del> fields, separated by spaces, there are per record in a file, and I was therefore planning to use non-advancing I/O to first count the number of <del>records</del> fields, then allocate a real array of sufficient size, and to finally read the file into that same array.

Here is an example input file (where the edit descriptor should be `f3.1` for every <del>record</del> field, i.e. a float 3 characters wide with one decimal, and counting the dot; although if I read Metcalf et al. correctly, the decimal is ignored):

```
1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0 5.0
```

And a MWE of my program looks like this

```
program testread
    use iso_fortran_env

    implicit none

    character(len=255) :: filename

    filename = 'read.dat'

    print *, count_entries(filename)

    contains
        integer function count_entries(coefficient_file) result(n)
            character(len=*), intent(in) :: coefficient_file
            !real, dimension(:), allocatable :: coefficients

            integer :: fileunit, stat
            real :: temp

            n=0

            open(newunit=fileunit, file=coefficient_file, iostat=stat)
                do
                    read(fileunit,'(f3.1)',advance='no',iostat=stat) temp
                    if (stat == iostat_end) then
                        exit
                    else
                        n = n + 1
                    end if
                    print *, stat, temp
                end do
            close(fileunit)

            ! What should happen in the future...
            !allocate(coefficients(n))
            !read(fileunit,*,iostat=stat) coefficients
        end function count_entries

end program testread
```

If you save the sample input above as `read.dat`, compile the program with `gfortran -o testread{,.f90}` and execute it, you will get the following result:

```
   0   1.00000000    
   0   2.00000000    
   0  0.300000012    
   0   0.00000000    
   0   4.00000000    
   0   5.00000000    
  -2   0.00000000    
   7
```

In other words, instead of counting 5 entries, it counts 7. And this is not surprising as it, for some reason, sees 7 numbers. But I wonder: why does it see 7 numbers? How can I extend my function to a) be able to also read larger reals and b) read reals of non-uniform width? For example, I would like to be able to read `1.01 1.003 2.1`, etc.

Comment: It is unfortunate that you apparently call record something different than what it means in the Fortran standard. Normally in text files one record is one line.

Comment: Sorry about that; I edited the parts of my question where I meant space-separated fields, but wrote “records”.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sees six numbers (the last one is an end of record condition) because your format specification specifies that three characters be read each time, but your data is spaced every four columns (three for the data, one for the separating blank).

If your input isn't fixed format (number of columns may vary), then read the whole record (line) into a `character(:), allocatable` variable and then manually chop that string up.

(Never use a format specification with a specified number of decimal places for input unless you know that your input will always suit that.)

Comment: In ##fortran on Freenode somebody pointed me to certik's Fortran utils, which contains the procedure `loadtxt` doing exactly what you suggested. So I ended up using that:
https://github.com/certik/fortran-utils/blob/master/src/utils.f90

Comment: @mSSM the actual implementation of `loadtxt` is actually very different, but it is a good choice.

Comment: @VladimirF I was thinking about how to implement this along the lines of what IanH suggested. But “chopping the string up”, as he puts it, would in my mind also entail walking along the string and determining when the next space comes, right? Or is there a more elegant way?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to account for the spaces. Just use `'(f3.1,1x)'`.